# Blackberry OS 6 Toolbar PushScreen and PopScreen

Tags: blackberry, toolbar

I asked a question before on how to create a Toolbar, where I am now is I have created the toolbar, and push on the next screen, but I am not sure how I can remove the last screen, I know you can use popScreen. What I am stuck at is popping a screen off in a tab bar, because I do not know what the last screen may be, since the I can click anyone of the tabs at the top. Can anyone provide me with some code samples on a app using the Tab Bar which adds the new screen and removes the last screen?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you want to leave screens on the stack, so that when the user is done with whatever activity they have selected, the toolbar screen is shown again.  If you know you want to pop the current screen, you can get it via `UiApplication.getActiveScreen()` which returns the topmost screen in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see any trouble here. Look, the toolbar is a field of some screen. Right? So if a toolbar btn is clicked, then you know what screen to pop off (the one the toolbar is on currently). Also you know what screen to push by knowing what toolbar button is clicked.